# KitchenAid Dishwasher Not Filling Up

Tags: plumbing, appliances, dishwasher

I have a KitchenAid KDTM354DSS4 Dishwasher.  Today we went to run it and it wouldn't fill up with water.  I filled it with water manually and it washes just fine.

I looked at the fill valve and unscrewed the water inlet to see if it was clogged.  It didn't appear to be.  I had a hard time completely removing the inlet valve.  I couldn't get the power connector off and the black hose was also really difficult to remove.

[Here is a video](https://imgur.com/a/d1PUfJk) of the inlet valve operating (it has audio) when I set the cycle to "rinse only".  Someone may know from the clicks and sounds whether the valve is working properly.

One other detail that I don't know is related or not: I recently flushed my hot water heater.  We did get some of the sediment come through the lines.  In retrospect I should have shut the water off to areas like the dishwasher, washing machine, etc.

[image: hot water to dishwasher]
[image: power connector]
[image]

Comment: was there any debris on the filter after the hose connector before the inlet valve?

Comment: did you remove the hose and verify free water flow before it gets to the dishwasher?

Comment: I didn't see any debris.  No I didn't verify free water flow before it gets to the dishwasher.  I need to do that.

Comment: was there a little screen before the valve after the hose connection?  I had a piece of solder make its way into the valve and prevent it from running that was 15 years ago though and there must not have been a screen before the valve on mine.

Comment: Yes there was a screen.

Answer (score 1):

You said "I filled it with water manually and it washes just fine."

If cleaning the screen and flushing out the water supply line doesn't work,
this could be a control issue. Meaning, the unit may not be ready to begin a new cycle for one reason or another- thus not calling for water on the valve. Try putting the water in it manually again, then hit cancel/drain. Do this a few times, and see if it resets your control. Then try a small load of dishes on a quick wash cycle to see if it works.